# Magento2: Remove Store Code URL only for default store

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, store-view

I am developing a Magento 2 store with two store views, one for each language(English and Italian). I turned on the "Add Store Code to Urls" option from backend, so my URLs looks like:

```
http://mystore.com/en (English)
http://mystore.com/it (Italian)
```

What I would like to do now is to remove the store code from URL for the default store view, to obtain something like this:

```
http://mystore.com/ (English)
http://mystore.com/it (Italian)
```

In Magento 1.9 there a few extensions that do this. I need to find something (or develop) for Magento 2.

Anyone has some hints?

A good example of what I am searching for is this:
https://github.com/lalitmohann/magento-hide-default-store-code

Comment: Use this extension for solve this problem https://www.safemage.com/advanced-url-store-code-magento-2.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement and was able to solve it easily with just one plugin for `Magento\Store\Model\Store::isUseStoreInUrl` method.

```
public function afterIsUseStoreInUrl(\Magento\Store\Model\Store $subject, $resultIsUseInUrl)
{
    if ($subject->getCode() != $subject::ADMIN_CODE && $subject->isDefault())
    {
        return $resultIsUseInUrl && $this->scopeConfig->getValue('web/url/use_store_in_default');
    }
    else
    {
        return $resultIsUseInUrl;
    }
}
```

I registered the plugin in global `di.xml` instead of frontend because the first time this method is called area has not yet been set so the plugin would not get executed.

Answer (score 1):

We created an extension for this issue. We used an after plugin on `Magento\Store\Model\Store::IsUseStoreInUrl` to check if the store code is not the admin store and if the store is the default store.
You can find the extension here : https://github.com/customgento/module-default-store-code-remover-m2

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new module in *Vendor/HideDefaultStoreCode*

*registration.php*

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_HideDefaultStoreCode',
    __DIR__
);
```

*etc/module.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_HideDefaultStoreCode" setup_version="0.1.0" />
</config>
```

2. Add an option to the admin panel

*etc/adminhtml/system.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="web">
            <group id="url">
                <field id="hide_default_store_code" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Hide Default Store Code</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Default option value is *No*

*etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <web>
            <url>
                <hide_default_store_code>0</hide_default_store_code>
            </url>
        </web>
    </default>
</config>
```

3. Add helper

*Helper/Data.php*

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const XML_PATH_HIDE_DEFAULT_STORE_CODE = 'web/url/hide_default_store_code';

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHideDefaultStoreCode()
    {
        if ($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_HIDE_DEFAULT_STORE_CODE, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

4. Create after-plugin

*etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Store\Model\Store">
        <plugin name="vendor_hide_default_store_code" type="\Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Plugin\Model\HideDefaultStoreCode" sortOrder="0" />
    </type>
</config>
```

*Plugin/Model/HideDefaultStoreCode.php*

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Plugin\Model;

class HideDefaultStoreCode
{
    /**
     *
     * @var \Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Helper\Data 
     */
    protected $helper;
    
    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param \Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Helper\Data $helper
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ){
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\Store $subject
     * @param string $url
     * @return string
     */
    public function afterGetBaseUrl(\Magento\Store\Model\Store $subject, $url)
    {
        if ($this->helper->isHideDefaultStoreCode()) {
            $url = str_replace('/'.$this->storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getCode().'/','/', $url);
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

My Plugin for hide *Default Store Code* - https://github.com/alex-79/magento2-hide-default-store-code-from-url

---

See answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/287830/37969

Answer (score -2):

**Turn off store code URLs in adminside**

```
admin > stores > configuration > General > Web > Add Store Code to Urls > To set NO
```

*After Run upgrade, static-content-deploy, and cache clean/flush commands.*

Comment: Mind that the OP only wants to remove the store code for the **default** store.