# Magento 2: Remove Store Code in URL only for default store

Tags: magento2, multistore, url

We run a magento 2 multistore in 2 langauges where default store view is german. Online shop is also available in french. Store code is added to URLs like the following:

```
www.domain.at
www.domain.at/de
www.domain.at/fr
```

When it comes to SEO we have the problem of duplicate content because the default store is available with **AND** without store code in `URL`. The following urls show the same content:

```
www.domain.at/de  
www.domain.at/
```

In fact we need same behavior like here for magento 1: [Magento remove "default" store code from urls](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111857/magento-remove-default-store-code-from-urls)

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 7):

1. Create new module in *Vendor/HideDefaultStoreCode*

*registration.php*

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_HideDefaultStoreCode',
    __DIR__
);
```

*etc/module.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_HideDefaultStoreCode" setup_version="0.1.0" />
</config>
```

2. Add an option to the admin panel

*etc/adminhtml/system.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="web">
            <group id="url">
                <field id="hide_default_store_code" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Hide Default Store Code</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Default option value is *No*

*etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <web>
            <url>
                <hide_default_store_code>0</hide_default_store_code>
            </url>
        </web>
    </default>
</config>
```

3. Add helper

*Helper/Data.php*

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const XML_PATH_HIDE_DEFAULT_STORE_CODE = 'web/url/hide_default_store_code';

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHideDefaultStoreCode()
    {
        if ($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_HIDE_DEFAULT_STORE_CODE, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

4. Create after-plugin

*etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Store\Model\Store">
        <plugin name="vendor_hide_default_store_code" type="\Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Plugin\Model\HideDefaultStoreCode" sortOrder="0" />
    </type>
</config>
```

*Plugin/Model/HideDefaultStoreCode.php*

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Plugin\Model;

class HideDefaultStoreCode
{
    /**
     *
     * @var \Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Helper\Data 
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Helper\Data $helper
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\HideDefaultStoreCode\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ){
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\Store $subject
     * @param string $url
     * @return string
     */
    public function afterGetBaseUrl(\Magento\Store\Model\Store $subject, $url)
    {
        if ($this->helper->isHideDefaultStoreCode()) {
            $url = str_replace('/'.$this->storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getCode().'/','/', $url);
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

My Plugin for hide *Default Store Code* - https://github.com/alex-79/magento2-hide-default-store-code-from-url

Comment: great extension, it worked for me. searching for hours.

Answer (score 6):

Preference `\Magento\Store\Model\Store`, override the following protected function.

```
protected function _updatePathUseStoreView($url)
{
    if ($this->isUseStoreInUrl()) {
        $url .= $this->getCode() . '/';
    }
    return $url;
}
```

with below code:

```
protected function _updatePathUseStoreView($url)
{
    if ($this->isUseStoreInUrl()) {
        if($this->getCode() == 'default'){
            $url .= '/';
        }else{
            $url .= $this->getCode() . '/';
        }

    }
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work with store switcher (store code pre-pended again)

Comment: use a plugin after the public function isUseStoreInUrl, its better than changing the di preference, more upgrade safe, thats why its there

Answer (score 3):

You can disable store codes via admin at below path

```
Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Web > URL options > Add Store Code to Urls > No
```

**Keep cache Disabled** or run upgrade/deploy/cache commands if you don't see the changes

Comment: We do not want to remove store codes from URL entirely. Only for default store view (= de)

Comment: can you pls help me for mageno 2.3 multi website https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/256694/57334 @Manoj Deswal

Comment: good job, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem. After research here, i have an solution based on Renk´s answer. In backend set the "add store code". Than create a di.xml in your extension path under "Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml" for an plugin.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="\Magento\Store\Model\Store">
            <plugin name="RemoveDefaultStorePath" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\RemoveDefaultStorePath" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
        </type>
    </config>
```

After that create the plugin class under "Vendor/Module/plugin/RemoveDefaultStorePath.php" with the follow function as "after" IsUseStoreInUrl to overwrite the standard behavior

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;


class RemoveDefaultStorePath
{
    public function afterIsUseStoreInUrl(\Magento\Store\Model\Store $subject, $resultIsUseInUrl)
    {
       if ($subject->getCode()==='default')
        {
          $resultIsUseInUrl = false;
          return $resultIsUseInUrl && 'default';
        }
        else
        {
          $resultIsUseInUrl = true;
          if(!$subject->getCode() ==='admin') {
            return $resultIsUseInUrl && $subject->getCode() . '/';
          } else {
            $resultIsUseInUrl = false;
            return $resultIsUseInUrl && $subject::ADMIN_CODE;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

And than compile and clean the cache.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

I hope that´s help somebody - in my environment i have now the "default" store url´s without any addtional "store_code" and for the other multisites stores the preferd code  "en"/"fr" etc. Please not: under the store config - don´t set the store code to url:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We created an extension for this issue. We used an after plugin on `Magento\Store\Model\Store::isUseStoreInUrl` to check if the store code is not the admin store and if the store is the default store.
You can find the extension here : https://github.com/customgento/module-default-store-code-remover-m2